# Variable number of reads from database before write clears data

Tags: asp.net, vb6

I have a desktop vb6 application that is loading into a webbrowser control an asp.net webpage generated at a remote website.
On this webpage are a label and a button.
The label is filled with text from an Access database on the website.

In the asp.net page_load procedure there is a function (in a loop) that returns the data from the database and while the value returned is an empty string the loop repeats.
So there will be a timeout about every 2 minutes if there is no data. 
Since the calling of the webpage by the vb6 app is itself inside a loop the webpage then gets called again

If there is data then the page_load completes.
Then the vb6 app clicks the button.
The server side code in the button's click eventhandler then edits the relevant database entry to an empty string.
This should mean that the vb6 app should not get the same data on the next call but what's happening is that the data might be sent 1,2,3,4.. times on successive calls before the data is cleared in the database.

I put in a delay of 0.5 second in the vb6 app after the button click and then everything worked as it should.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: More details are required like code sample, you should also mention the problem which you are trying to resolve by this technique, you might get good suggestions.

Comment: Though i could not get the problem, it could be that your VB6 loop loads the page before your last web request gets completed.

Comment: @bjan Thank you very much for suggesting I post the code. On tidying it up to make it presentable ;) i discovered that a variable 'PageFinished' that gets set to true inside the sub 'WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete' wasn't being set to false before the button click which in turn meant I wasn't waiting for the request to be completed. duh!! Sorry I can't vote for you, if you post an answer and I'll accept it. The point of this is to try to implement long polling so a local vb6 app can be controlled from a webpage

Comment: It is ok, you post your findings as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"More details are required like code sample, you should also mention the problem which you are trying to resolve by this technique, you might get good suggestions.
"**it could be that your VB6 loop loads the page before your last web request gets completed**. – bjan

This was it, I wasn't waiting for the document to be completed.